# Which browsers allow to add multiple tags (keywords) to a bookmark?

Tags: browser, bookmarks, keyword

I know that in Firefox I can assign multiple keywords to a bookmark.
Though until now I knew of no tool to query for the bookmarks which have
a combination of two or three keywords. Well I know that Firefox stores
its bookmarks in a sqlite3 database, `places.sqlite` and it is little
difficult to query that database.

But what about all the competing browsers? Which are capable of assigning multiple keywords to a bookmark and store their bookmarks in some open format?

**EDIT:**

Here is for example the query for all bookmarks which are tagged 'hot' and 'sql'

```
SELECT * from moz_bookmarks b
    join moz_bookmarks l1 on b.fk = l1.fk and b.id <> l1.id
    join moz_bookmarks t1 on l1.parent = t1.id and  t1.parent = 4 and upper(t1.title) = upper('hot')
    join moz_bookmarks l2 on b.fk = l2.fk and b.id <> l2.id
    join moz_bookmarks t2 on l2.parent = t2.id and  t2.parent = 4 and upper(t2.title) = upper('sql')
where b.title is not null and b.type = 1
```

you can execute the query for example in the SQLite Manager Firefox AddOn.

Let me repose my question, is Firefox the only browser which collects bookmarks in an intelligent way, i.e. with the chance to find something, after you have same thousand bookmarks. You never had the problem I must have bookmarked it, but I can't find it?

Comment: Chrome has an extension **[Bookmark Tagging](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/bookmarks-tagging/kmdepbjjhlbhohppiancfgdpkjcoajgb)** to manage bookmarks with tags.

Answer (score 1):

I often use this feature and the only browsers I have used are Firefox, IE and Chrome. I am using Chrome as my default browser.

The only way I managed to get keywords working with Chrome is by creating the bookmarks with Firefox and adding the keywords to the bookmarks, followed by exporting them from Firefox and then importing them from the Chrome bookmark manager. You will then be able to use the keywords in Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

This is almost certainly not the answer you are looking for, but [uzbl](http://www.uzbl.org/). You manage everything yourself, including bookmarks, so you can write scripts for querying bookmarks.

Comment: That seems to target linux users.